# How to refactor in spyder?

Tags: python, refactoring, spyder

I have been looking at how "refactor" in Spyder IDE (5.4.3), that is rename a variable and all occurrences of it in the script.

I only found very old similar topics (5 years old and older where Spyder was 3.x version). Also, I don't find satisfying the solution that consists of "replacing" occurrences of text:
it is problematic if you want to change a short name variable like 'i'. The 'i' letter is everywhere in the code, although when the variable i is selected in Spyder, the correct i variables are highlighted throughout the code, but the letter 'i' (variable or not) will be replaced...

Does anyone have a solution now that it is Spyder 5 and that it is a very important feature?

Comment: just recommend you swap spyder to pycharm that does this (and many other) thing great.

Comment: I was using pycharm, but it is so slow to run code for unknown reasons, that is why I moved to spyder..